# How to run MPI on VS Code or Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, mpi

I have a need to run MPI on Windows 10, so I tried to install the library on Visual Studio, but each time I create a new project it requires repeating the process from the beginning, meaning I have to add dependencies all over again.
The first question is it possible to install the MPI once and for all and the second is if it's possible to run it on VS Code instead of Studio.

Comment: I assume you are referring to GUI changes in the project settings? Those changes end up in the `vcxproj` files. If you copy those snippets directly into a `Directory.Build.props` or `Directory.Build.targets` file in the solution base directory, it will be automatically imported into the msbuild project.

Comment: You can create a new project template for Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it via this guide
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=msvc-160
Seems to work now without needing each time to add dependencies, does not run on Vscode though, says some error with the .json I don't know what exactly but I can run in Visual Studio so it's okay for now.